# Can I customize a Jackson ObjectMapper by adding a module?

Tags: java, jackson, tinkerpop3

I am [using a library](https://github.com/tinkerpop/tinkerpop3/blob/711b86a463b7c438592502cedc513e7d48636eed/gremlin-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/io/graphson/GraphSONMapper.java) that creates an `ObjectMapper` and adds some `Module`s of its own to this mapper. I would like the serializers in these modules to pretty print. However, my only access to configure this mapper is via a [builder that lets me add my own modules](https://github.com/tinkerpop/tinkerpop3/blob/711b86a463b7c438592502cedc513e7d48636eed/gremlin-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/io/graphson/GraphSONMapper.java#L80-L82). Can I use my ability to add modules to the `ObjectMapper` to configure it to pretty print? I'm not seeing any methods or properties of [`SimpleModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule.html) suggesting that I can.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you can register a `Module` with an `ObjectMapper`, you can manipulate the mapper. Override the `setupModule()` method on the `Module` and then use `getOwner()` on the `Module.SetupContext` that you get:

```
GraphSONMapper mapper = GraphSONMapper.build().addCustomModule(new SimpleModule() {                                          
    public void setupModule(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module.SetupContext context) {                                    
        ObjectMapper mapper = context.getOwner();                                                                            
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                        
}).create();                                                                                                                 
GraphSONWriter writer = graph.io().graphSONWriter().mapper(mapper).create();
```

The documentation for `getOwner()` suggests you shouldn't do this unless you have to.

Comment: It is worth noting that enabling `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT` [will only enable use of default pretty printing](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#INDENT_OUTPUT), which includes two lines of indentation. TBD how to gracefully override indentation.

Comment: I'm thinking that this falls into the "or there are oversights" part of the doc in `getOwner()`. `GraphSONMapper` has the instantiation of `ObjectMapper` hardcoded internally instead of abstracted somehow, making it seemingly impossible to configure the mapper directly but there must be a way.