# What is the simplest way to configure the indentation spacing on a Jackson ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm really struggling with the degree of complexity I am perceiving in solving this problem. As the title says: **What is a simple way to create a Jackson `ObjectMapper` with a 4-space `PrettyPrinter`?**

Bonus points: How can I **modify an existing** `ObjectMapper` to make it pretty print 4 spaces?

Through my research, I've found that the simplest way is to enable pretty printing generally is to set `INDENT_OUTPUT` on the mapper:

```
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

However, this only enables the the `DefaultPrettyPrinter`, which has 2 spaces of indentation. I would like 4. To do this, it seems like I have to construct my own `ObjectMapper`, providing a `JsonFactory` with a `JsonGenerator` that has a `PrettyPrinter` that does 4 spaces. This is way too intense for something that is so so so simple on other platforms. Please tell me there is a simpler way.

Comment: This is a cool problem. Just curious, is this behavior desired for purely cosmetic reasons or is there actually a constraint somewhere that is requiring you to use 4 space indentation?

Comment: I tried putting something _real_ nasty together with reflection and decided it probably isn't even humorous. I think the idea is behind the clunkiness is: it is equally as clunky no matter how complex your config needs to be. You will likely need to follow the Jackson prescribed method to apply this globally on your existing mapper (sadpanda)

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks for thinking about this. I guess the use-case constraint for me is cosmetic meets practical meets lame: I was trying to log the contents of a graph using the GraphSON module provided in Tinkerpop3. Debugging logging JSON is most useful to me when there is a lot of indentation. Here's the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255878/can-i-customize-a-jackson-objectmapper-by-adding-a-module

Comment: It is making my brain explode how difficult it is to configure indentation globally! It goes ObjectMapper > JsonFactory > JsonGenerator from highest to lowest abstraction, and it seems like the only place to set pretty print config explicitly is in JsonGenerator. Having to call `.writer(...)` every time you want this config seems ridiculous.

Comment: @SamB. saw that you saw my other question. Crazy, right? Given the way that class is set up, that's just how it is I think. Private constructor, no way to inject a mapper or functionality otherwise, so nothing doing it seems. Anyway, thankfully I'm just using this for debug logging. So no biggie really. I've been left with the conclusion that Jackson is a large, complicated solution for the large and complicated problem of serializing and deserializing typed structures to and from a format that is the serialization of untyped structures of another language. So it goes I guess?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the *simplest* way to go but... You can use the `ObjectMapper` with a custom printer. The `DefaultPrettyPrinter` can be used if you modify the indent behaviour.

```
// Create the mapper
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Setup a pretty printer with an indenter (indenter has 4 spaces in this case)
DefaultPrettyPrinter.Indenter indenter = 
        new DefaultIndenter("    ", DefaultIndenter.SYS_LF);
DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
printer.indentObjectsWith(indenter);
printer.indentArraysWith(indenter);

// Some object to serialize
Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("foo", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

// Serialize it using the custom printer
String json = mapper.writer(printer).writeValueAsString(value);

// Print it
System.out.println(json);
```

The output will be:

```
{
    "foo" : [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had been missing a couple of things that you point out here.

Comment: You can use `mapper.setDefaultPrettyPrinter(printer);` to make the custom printer in this answer the default one for your object mapper.  You're still required to enable indenting through `mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)`.

Comment: @wassgren is there a way to remove the space before the colon for every element? i.e. the space before colon in `"foo" : [` ?

Comment: `printer = printer.withoutSpacesInObjectEntries();  // default is withSpacesInObjectEntries()` however it will remove all spaces: `"foo":[` so I will just convert my final string. Expecting that result structure will always be `"foo" : [`, I use `result.replace("\" : \"", "\": \"")` documentation [here](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.6.1/deprecated-list.html)

Comment: This is difficult to find any useful documentation on, thank you

Comment: Perfect answer to the question and what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

it very simple to do that, you don't need to implement any interface/Abstract Class.
Create only a new printer and use it as argument of mapper writer :

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter().withObjectIndenter(new DefaultIndenter("    ", "\n"));
    String json = mapper.writer(printer).writeValueAsString(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on very helpful @wassgren answer, and to answer to @Kervvv question too, I give you my answer to this problem:

I improve a bit the solution to meet my requirements

1. no space, after the field name
2. no space between square bracket for empty array

You need Jackson 2.9 at least

```
public class MyPrettyPrinter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter {

  public MyPrettyPrinter() {
    DefaultPrettyPrinter.Indenter indenter = new DefaultIndenter("    ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    indentObjectsWith(indenter);
    indentArraysWith(indenter);
    _objectFieldValueSeparatorWithSpaces = ": ";
  }

  private MyPrettyPrinter(MyPrettyPrinter pp) {
    super(pp);
  }

  @Override
  public void writeEndArray(JsonGenerator g, int nrOfValues) throws IOException {
    if (!_arrayIndenter.isInline()) {
      --_nesting;
    }
    if (nrOfValues > 0) {
      _arrayIndenter.writeIndentation(g, _nesting);
    }
    g.writeRaw(']');
  }

  @Override
  public DefaultPrettyPrinter createInstance() {
    return new MyPrettyPrinter(this);
  }
}
```

And usage

```
mapper.writer(new MyPrettyPrinter()).writeValueAsString(value);
```

Comment: Thanks. May i know which line of code is for removing space in empty array.  If i purely wanted to remove space in empty array, is there a way to do it in a concise manner without having to implement or extend any class

Comment: As I known no you can't that one reason why I overwrite DefaultPrettyPrinter.writeEndArray method, if you compare with original, you may see that I don't write the space. here => `if (nrOfValues > 0) {..} else { g.writeRaw(' '); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to write multiple objects, as I did, to get JSON comparison in a JUnit test running in IntelliJ (which has a very nice multiline compare tool):

```
// could likely be simplified to `new ObjectMapper().writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter())`
ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper()
        .setDefaultPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter())
        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();

try {
    String expected = writer.writeValueAsString(testCase.getThing());
    String actual = writer.writeValueAsString(actual.getThing());
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    fail("JSON exception: " + e.toString());
}
```