# Is it possible to indent curly brackets with jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to serialize object to json using Jackson ObjectMapper and I am aware of DefaultIndenter and DefaultPrettyPrinter features but I still can't find a way (not sure if it is possible) to indent "{" and "}" which are wrapping json object. 
So, currently I can do this:

```
{
    "prop1":"val1",
    "prop2":"val2"
}
```

But, I would like to indent with "{" and "}" with 4 spaces, and values with 8 spaces:

```
    {
        "prop1":"val1",
        "prop2":"val2"
    }
```

Is it possible to do this with ObjectMapper?

Comment: This is answered here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256852/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-configure-the-indentation-spacing-on-a-jackson-objec>

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I already found this answer and it is not answer on my question. Brackets wrapping json object will not be indented  even if use DefaultIndenter and DefaultPrettyPrinter.