# Pretty print Jackson json without whitespaces?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `json` string that I want to pretty print with `jackson`. The following works in general:

```
    ObjectWriter w = new ObjectMapper()
            .writer()
            .withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

    Object obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Object.class);
    System.out.println(w.writeValueAsString(obj));
```

Result:

```
{
   "myarray" : [ {
      "field" : "val"
   } ]
}
```

BUT: I'd like to get the output without whitespaces between parameters. Is  that possible?

Desired output:

```
{
   "myarray":[{
      "field":"val"
   }]
}
```

Comment: You can provide your own `PrettyPrinter` instance for `ObjectMapper` to use. For eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256852/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-configure-the-indentation-spacing-on-a-jackson-objec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can customise the `DefaultPrettyPrinter` with the followings:

- Use `withoutSpacesInObjectEntries()` to turn off spaces
  inside the object entries
- Set the array indenter to `DefaultPrettyPrinter.NopIndenter` such that there is  no spaces to separate the array value.

Code wise , it looks like :

```
DefaultPrettyPrinter pp = new DefaultPrettyPrinter()
            .withoutSpacesInObjectEntries()
            .withArrayIndenter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter.NopIndenter());

ObjectWriter w = new ObjectMapper()
            .writer()
            .with(pp);
```

It will output the JSON with the format like :

```
{
  "users":[{
    "name":"u1",
    "age":10
  },{
    "name":"u2",
    "age":20
  }]
}
```

Comment: ty so much! Are there any other whitespaces that could occur inside a serialized json object? I'd just want to have `INDENT_OUTPUT` without whitespaces anywhere.

Comment: I add an example about how the JSON will look like. is it what you want?

Comment: yes, exactly. I ment: if there are further whitespace occurrences that I'd have to deactivate? Or just the "in objects" and "in array"?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to get something like this (spaces only after colons and entities of the array are separated by line breaks)

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "u1",
      "age": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "u2",
      "age": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

you should use custom `PrettyPrinter` implementation:

```
public class CustomPrettyPrinter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter {
    public CustomPrettyPrinter() {
        super._arrayIndenter = new DefaultIndenter();
        super._objectFieldValueSeparatorWithSpaces = _separators.getObjectFieldValueSeparator() + " ";
    }

    @Override
    public CustomPrettyPrinter createInstance() {
        return new CustomPrettyPrinter();
    }
}
```

using the following code:

```
ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper()
        .writer()
        .with(new CustomPrettyPrinter());
String result = writer.writeValueAsString(obj);
```

Comment: Using `_arrayIndenter = new DefaultIndenter();` is not what the OP asked for as it will put every array element on new lines. Otherwise this is a helpful answer though.