# How to modify jackson jsonnode and write pretty json back in scala

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I can read/modify the json node with ObjectMapper. But I didn't find a way to write a **pretty** json back to a file.

```
val reader = new FileReader("env_config.json")
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()

// need to cast to ObjectNode because JsonNode is immutable
val objectNode = mapper.readTree(reader).asInstanceOf[ObjectNode]

// modify a field
objectNode("service_port", 1234)

// write back but not pretty
mapper.writeValue(Paths.get("env_config.json").toFile, objectNode)

// not working either
mapper.writeValue(Paths.get("env_config.json").toFile, objectNode.toPrettyString)
```

Comment: You need to enable [INDENT_OUTPUT](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#INDENT_OUTPUT) feature on `ObjectMapper`. Take a look at [What is the simplest way to configure the indentation spacing on a Jackson ObjectMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256852/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-configure-the-indentation-spacing-on-a-jackson-objec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using the INDENT_OUTPUT feature Michal suggested, I find an easy way to do pretty print:

```
val reader = new FileReader("env_config.json")
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()

// need to cast to ObjectNode because JsonNode is immutable
val objectNode = mapper.readTree(reader).asInstanceOf[ObjectNode]

// modify a field
objectNode("service_port", 1234)

// pass a DefaultPrettyPrinter instance to do the pretty print!
val writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
writer.writeValue(Paths.get("env_config.json").toFile, objectNode)
```

Cheers!